# Why is this code applying to the body tag instead of target?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, widget, raphael

I'm using a jQuery UI widget based plugin to apply SVG via Raphael to an element - instead of applying to the inside of the element I've selected using this code...

```
$('#red-dial').dial({
  barColor: '#F1858F',
  barValue: 26
});​
```

...it seems to be adding the SVG content just before the closing BODY tag. This is strange as within my plugin logging 'this.element' to the console shows the correct HTML item #red-dial is selected, and the same code was working before I converted it into a widget plugin.

Anyone know why this could be? Sure it's probably a dumb error on my part!

Full JSFiddle of all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vQJng/4/

Update: I've figured out that the script is inserting the SVG after the script file I call the widget from. For instance if I put the code:

```
$('#red-dial').dial({
  barColor: '#F1858F',
  barValue: 26
});
```

in the end of the widget file, the SVG is inserted the line after the widgets script file tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is anything to do with your widget; I think this is just the behaviour of Raphael.

As an example, I've just created a new Raphael canvas instead of using your widget and it generates the same layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/vQJng/5/

[image]

Comment: Afraid not. In a previous version of the code (non-widget, using a jQuery plugin boilerplate) the SVG is successfully inserted into the div. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/db3Td/1/

Comment: It seems the SVG code is being inserted after the script tag which calls the file with the selector for the widget inside it, rather than inside the selector specified HTML. Bizarre!